# How to get only the filename with Jersey File Upload

Tags: java, file-upload, jersey

I'm doing a file upload with Jersey, but I need only the filename. Internet Explorer sends the entire path, and based on what's in FormDataContentDisposition, Jersey parses out the slashes, so I can't even parse that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a difficult issue. The ideal case of course is to grab the string containing the slashes and just use string.split!

Failing that, the only strategy i can begin to think of is to try iterating through the string seeing if folders exist for various lengths of the first part of the string etc. This can cause problems too though if you intend to find a folder "MyFolder (2)" and theres also a "MyFolder". I don't know alot about jersey but i would recommend trying to find a different way to grab the string you need.

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing was add a change event to the file input tag and in it parse out the filename as it still has slashes at this point, and stick that value into a hidden input. That hidden input then gets submitted along with the rest of the form.

Comment: add your answer to this question rather than putting it in a comment , so that it would be more applicable

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a change event to the file input tag
2. Parse out the filename as it still has slashes at this point
3. Stick that value into a hidden input

That hidden input then gets submitted along with the rest of the form.

---

@kombat has found this solution and posted it as a comment. For better this is now reposted as a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error when I tried the Eclipse browser. When I tried my code on Chrome, the FormDataContentDisposition.getFileName() was fine.